# Validate title function

Tags: javascript, string, function, numbers, cycle

Write a title validation function - validateTitle, which takes an argument and validates it by the rules:

- Title length must be less than 2 characters but less than 20.
- Title must start with an uppercase letter
- Function should return ‘VALID’ if the string meets the requirements or ‘INVALID’ if it does not. And return 'Incorrect input data' if the given argument not a string. Do not use regular expressions.
  My solution is not full

  ```
    const validateTitle = (value) => {
    if (typeof value !== "string") {
      return "Incorrect input data";
    }
    for (let i = 2; i <= 19; i++) {}
  };
  ```

  Examples: validateTitle(false) // 'Incorrect input data'
  validateTitle([]) // 'Incorrect input data'
  validateTitle('s') // 'INVALID
  validateTitle('12title') // 'INVALID'
  validateTitle('Title!') // 'VALID'
  validateTitle('Title?') // 'VALID'

Comment: Title length must be less than 2 characters but less than 20 ?? what does it means ??

Comment: it means that title must be more than 2 symbols and less than 20 symbols

Comment: This reads as a copy & paste homework question - What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: const validateTitle = (value) => {
    if(typeof value !== 'string') {
      return 'Incorrect input data'
    }
for(let i = 2; i <= 19; i++ ) {
  if(!value.toUpperCase()) {
    return 'true'
  } else {
    return 'false'
  }
}
  }

Comment: i tried to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validTitle(tempString){
 let validFlag = ((tempString.charAt(0) == tempString.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) && 
                 (tempString.length > 2 && tempString.length < 20 )) ? true : false;
  return validFlag ? 'VALID' : 'INVALID'
}
```

try this -

Comment: I have edited it. (GREATER THAN SYMBOL WAS WRONG AND I MISS A BRACKET ) Now its working